# Forced using ppa's which only supports newer OSes

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, software-installation, ppa

I have a problem: I'm added a ppa, which currently states 13.10 (removing soon) and 14.04 support.
I would like to try force install a package from this ppa on my old 12.04 LTS without my OS version check.
How I could to do it?

Comment: You risk having unmet dependencies and therefore not being able to use the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

On the PPA page, in the section labelled "Technical details about this PPA", select the option to display the Saucy entries. Copy the first line (the second line is not required), and open up Software Sources (might be called Software & Updates). In the Other Software tab, add a new entry, and paste that line. Run `sudo apt-get update` and (try to) install the package you want to install.

Note that there might be a good reason the maintainer doesn't have packages for Precise. You might want to try to contact him to see if the software can be run on Precise.